# C# in Linux. What is the best approach?

Tags: c#, linux

My preferred environment is Linux. Recently I have wanted to improve my C# skills. What are the best methods and tools to program in C# and compile without having to change operating systems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203171/developing-c-sharp-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications:
http://www.mono-project.com/

MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and web applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X. It also makes it easy for developers to port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to Linux and Mac OS X maintaining a single code base for all platforms:
http://www.monodevelop.com/