# Building C# Application from Windows to linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, monodevelop, cross-compiling

Hi everyone firstly I am trying to develop a app with an interface for the Raspberri Pi 2. I am developing from my windows machine but want to build and use the application on the Pi.

I am trying to achieve this using C# only. Is there a way to do this from visual studio and if not how do I go about it on MonoDevelop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203211/2323245 :) 
but now microsoft is migrating to open-source, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx, take a look.