# Linux chat server with c#

Tags: c#, linux, windows, server, chat

I am quite new in programming so i'm looking for some advice.
Basically I learn C# on win8 until last week, when i started to show some interest in Linux Distros...and of course i installed it too.I really like this OS but it's a bit strange for me after win, by the way i'm sedulous in learning booth linux and programming.

My question is that...I would like to write a simple chat program that could communicate with a win7 client(Gf) and that sounds cool except linux is not windows :D. So I would like to know...What should i do? Change to Python or etc?Is it possible to make it in C#?I just need some "pointer" to select the best option of"route". :D

Comment: Everything is possible. At least [one implementation of the .NET framework](http://www.mono-project.com/) can run on Linux.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make it in C#?

Yes, you can use C# to develop a chat server on Linux and you can write portable code in C# (so that it can be run on multiple platforms).

See this related question:
[Developing C# on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11203171/688958)

Comment: this is probably more a comment than an answer

Comment: Really? I think it is an answer to the question: *Is it possible to make it in c#?*

Comment: Probably the problem lies in answering a super broad question.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree on that. But I believe that the OP need some guidance on where to get started to narrow down the "problem set".

Comment: (I didn't downvote but...) probably it is best to offer such useful guidance in comments. Then, if needed, post a complete answer. Otherwise we are kind of giving the wrong message to new users, who may understand that asking well is not necessary.

Comment: Ok. I have no problem with that. I just don't like it when these kind of questions get closed without giving the OP a "chance to continue". It makes me sad because it might kill the creative coding spirit of the OP.

Comment: Yes, I do agree on this point. However, in my experience broad questions that get answered very fast become very tiring for the answerer: the OP keeps narrowing down more and more once you answered, becoming an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/209901) in most of the cases.

Answer (score -1):

Look at .NET Core 1.0, it allows create truly cross-platform applications