# which platform for porting C# application to Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, shell, porting

I'm goint to port my C# application to Linux. My C# application read text files, manipulate its data, and split it to segments using below data commands and data structures:

```
    List<string> linesReadList;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1;
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

I know that every development environment got its nature, however I want to know is there any development environment close to C# in Linux?

I want to run my application in shell script and also development environment can support high-level data structures to speed up my development.

Comment: If you want to run your application in a shell script, you don't want an `OpenFileDialog`... why don't you just accept the filename as a command-line argument? Then you could keep it in C# using Mono or .NET Core, apart from anything else...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203171/developing-c-sharp-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: use C# and 
[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/linux/).

Mono is a port of the .Net Framework and works great under Linux.
I tested it on a Raspberry with Debian.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mono, you also now have Microsoft's own [.NET Core](http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/netcore). It is less feature full than Mono, and it is currently very much in beta, but for your purposes it may present no practical difference.