# Writing C# on Linux with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

I read the question *[Developing C# on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203171/developing-c-sharp-on-linux)* and most people answered recommended to use [MonoDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) to write C# on Linux. What about Visual Studio Code? Did anyone try to write C# on Linux with this IDE? Did it work well?

Comment: .net core should be one of the best framework to go. I do not know about the other

Answer (score 5):

Now, [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) is available and supports quite good cross-platform development opportunities. (Even, if you are developing on Windows, but you would like to run your code on a Linux-based system.)

For developing on Linux, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is one of the best tools - in my humble opinion - and it's being developed/improved every second nowadays. You can find several **Extensions** to help you out, such as the [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp).

Anyhow, once you run Visual Studio Code and begin your development process, the application will try to detect your needs, and you will be prompted to install several extensions, which might be useful for you (such as the C# extension, debuggers, documentations, etc.)

It is not a real Visual Studio (and in some cases not even MonoDevelop) - yet -, but - as I said - it is under development now, and gives nice support for C# and even ASP.NET development on Linux. It is on the way to become a powerful and light weighted tool on operating systems, where Visual Studio can't run.

*Note: If you haven't used .NET Core before, it might be the best to check some of the differences first, for example the usage of the **.json** configuration files, used by your solution and projects.*